# Continue number series when using a placeholder value in <input type="number">

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I would like to continue with numbers when using a placeholder in an input form.

Let's say my placeholder value is 5:

`<input id="threshold" type="number" placeholder="5" value="">`

I would like user to be able click on arrow up and value in a form would go to 6 (then 7, 8..). Instead, if user clicks on arrow up, values in the form would start on number 1 (then 2, 3...). Similar with arrow down - the value in the form would go to -1, instead of 4.

I can achieve desired behavior if I give up on placeholder and specify value, like this: `<input id="threshold" type="number" value="5">`

But let's say, I really want user to continue with numbers depending on placeholder value, because I like a gray look of input placeholder, is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: A solution should also work with restrictions on `min` and `max` value of input number.

Comment: Can you post enough of your current ("*[mcve]*") code to allow us to reproduce your problem? The "start," and then show us -specifically, ideally in the HTML - what you want to end up with? "* I really want user to continue with numbers depending on placeholder value, because I like a gray look of input placeholder*" - this sounds like you want the numbers to look like placeholders, but be list-numbering (or similar). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I had thought, there would be only minor piece of puzzle I missed. In the light of new information and self-disproved assumption ("Using placeholders wouldn't send non-changed values to Django app"), my problem should be really redefined to "change color of input", this I can find elsewhere. Shall I though keep this question (minus edit about specification about `min` and `max`) and accept correct answer? And maybe post comment about my redefinition, in case anyone else would have the same chain of thoughts as I did?

Comment: Sadly, you can only achieve this if you use Javascript. Twisting the original HTML concepts is usually a bit of work (if at all possible in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

Here some example i dont know if that what u searching for

```html
<p>input with min max from 10 to 100 with start value 10</p>
<input type="number" value="10" min="10" max="100">
<br>
<p>input with min from 10 with start value 10</p>
<input type="number" value="10" min="10" >
<br>
<p>input with max 100 with start value 10</p>
<input type="number" value="10" max="100">
```

Comment: Thank you. However, as I said using "value" works fine, I would like this behavior with "placeholder"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In this demo I add two event listener to the `#threshold` element:

- For the `keyup` event, to keep track of when the user typed the
  value with the keyboard instead of using the arrow buttons, and
  discard the automatic behaviour based on placeholder in that case.
- For the `input` event, to catch whenever the user is sending input,
  both with the arrow keys and the keyboard.If such event occurs when
  the value is still empty, it will be overridden by a value that won't
  start by 1/-1 but from the placeholder+1/-1. The handler will discard
  the occurrence in case it happened pressing the keyboard instead of
  the mouse.

As far as I know, there's no other way to discern the exact event occurred between inserting value with keyboard or by clicking the arrows so the only way I found was keeping track of the keypress happening one moment before the input itself and try my best to discard some rare occurrencies when those conditions where not sufficient.

It works but I'm not perfectly sure how it fits in accessibility terms.
But yet i can mention the scenarios in which I could test it as working:

- When the input is still empty, clicking the arrow up/down will
  increment and decrement starting from 5 as the zero (placeholder).
- When the input is still empty, typing the numbers inside with the
  keyboard won't trigger the override logic.
- When the input is filled with a valid number, clicking the arrow
  up/down will increment and decrement starting from the number
  currently filling the field.
- When the input is filled with a valid number, selecting the value and
  pressing backspace or del (or delete the value by any means), will
  reset the state of the control so that when pressing the arrows
  up/down will follow the expected logic where the zero becomes the
  placeholder again.

```js
const o = document.querySelector('#threshold');
o.dataset.previous = '';

o.addEventListener('input', (event)=>{  

  //This shows the value of the input (as decided from browser)
  //when the input event gets fired...
  //Unfortunately when min attribute is set, and the value of the input is still blank,
  //the value chosen by the browser (when pressing up/down arrows),
  //is always equal to that min attribute value.
  //Otherwise it was -1 or +1 based on pressing respectively the down or up arrow.
  //So in that scenario there's no way to discrern if the arrow hit was up or down.
  console.log(event.target.value);
  //So far the problem remains impossible to solve with the current strategy 
  //because there's no specific event fired to understand that detail
  //to say the whole story, placeholder was not intended to be used that way nor the arrow
  //were supposed to be in control of the page... this was just a trick I did here.
  //And unfortunately it wasn't powerful enough to cover the min/max scenario.
    
  const el = event.target;    
  
  if (el.dataset.prevent === true || el.dataset.previous !== ''){
    el.dataset.prevent = false;    
    return false;    
  } 
  
  if( el.getAttribute('min') !== null && el.value === el.getAttribute('min') )
    el.value = parseInt(el.placeholder) - 1;
  else if(el.value === '1')
    el.value = parseInt(el.placeholder) + 1;
  else if(el.value === '-1')
    el.value = parseInt(el.placeholder) - 1;
  
  el.dataset.previous = el.value;    
});

o.addEventListener('keyup',(event)=>{
  const el = event.target;    
  if(el.value !== '')  
    el.dataset.prevent = true;    
  else{
    el.dataset.prevent = false;    
    el.dataset.previous = '';    
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="threshold" type="number" placeholder="5" max="10">

<!--
Example of input (having the same id) with min attribute set
<input id="threshold" type="number" placeholder="5" max="10">
-->
```

Comment: Hello, this works like a magic on the example! Thank you. I have came across one issue, though. As my input have also min and max specified `<input id="threshold" type="number" placeholder="5" min="0" max="9223372036854775807">`, the input value would drop all the way down to 0 -everytime I click on arrow down or key down. For incrementing, it is working as expected, though.

Comment: I didn't consider the min/max because you didn't specify them in your original question otherwise my answer maybe would have taken that into account

Comment: Yes, that's problem on my side. I made a decision to simplify my problem a bit. On top of that, firstly, I am using `min` and `max` restriction, secondly for placeholder value I use a number passed to template by django view. Shall I edit my original question, then?

Comment: if you change the way the placeholder gets rendered I don't know how it will affect my answer.. but I guess that won't make much difference. But yes you can change your question especially talking about the min max restriction but I can't assure you I'll have time to edit my answer. For sure not today. Anyway in genearal is a bad practice because it invalidates the time required to solve your problem as you stated it at the beginning

Comment: I tried in the past few minutes to see how the min max would affect my logic and it's actually non trivial because I rely on the value sent to the input and it gets overridden to the min when you start from blank state. I'm afraid it won't be very easy and it will involve at least doing considerations with the previous value beyond what I did already. I don't know if I'll be helpful at all. I'm sorry

Comment: I do not rush for solution. I will keep in mind, next time, to don't oversimplify my problem. Thank you for your time, if you would want to spend more time improving this logic, that is fine, but if you don't it is also fine. Have a nice day!

Comment: I updated the solution with an explanation on why it's impossible for my strategy to go any further and discern the pressing of down/up button when using the min attribute. I wrote that on the answer only to leave it archived in history. I couldn't go any further unfortunately. I wish you will find a way somehow. Maybe it needs to just rewrite the input box with a custom one having control of custom arrows.